# break lines on a textbox when editing a database input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a working php crud, now I need to give some format the textboxes in the update page, so user can read/edit very long descriptions. I know I can only use textboxes for editing functions (textareas doesn't renders the text from the database), so I need some textboxes that behave as a multiline box.

What I have is this

```
<input type="text" class="textbox" name='description' value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($description, ENT_QUOTES);  ?>">
```

This load the content from the database into the textbox, but it shows a long string of text (up to 5000 characters).

First tried this CSS, but it breaks the words anywhere between to letters, anyway it only worked on Safari on Mac.

```
.textbox{
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    resize: none;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-word;
}
```

The with this other

```
.textbox{
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    resize: none;
    word-wrap: normal;
    word-break: normal;
}
```

But do nothing...so I'm looking for new ideas maybe with javascript / jquery or another solution.

Any ideas...

Comment: Elen, I do think a textarea would be a good fit for you, why exactly does it not render the text from the database?

Comment: Input type="text" can't be multiline. Uses textarea. The assertion «textareas doesn't renders the text from the database» is false.

Comment: Well, maybe I did something wrong, I will check back and try again with a <textarea>. I first tried with `<textarea class="TextArea" name='description' value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($description, ENT_QUOTES);  ?>">` but when I enter in the update page the text area doesn't call the database input (text not loaded), but maybe I wrote something wrong. Will try again.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have commented, the behavior you are describing is exactly that of a [TextArea](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp). Here is a working example using the styling you described above, keeping in the PHP code provided.

```css
.TextArea {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="TextArea" name='description'>
  <?php echo htmlspecialchars($description, ENT_QUOTES);  ?>
</textarea>
```

Edit: Rather than using the value attribute as was originally copied, text areas should use the inner content. I haven't used PHP in quite a while, but I don't see an error with the insertion.

Comment: Still doesn't work...

I have replaced all the <input type="text"> with <textarea ...> (just copied and pasted the code from here) <textarea>, but when I review the document all the text areas are empty (content from the database is gone), if I change them back to text boxes the content from the database appears again.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check out the edit, but I would verify that your PHP code would generate inside of a div correctly as inner content first. Check the DOM and ensure that it is valid. Otherwise, textareas are pretty simple HTML elements.